# How to get environment variables in pre build steps?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a jenkins job that releases modules.

Pre Build Step:

-> Before release build

-> After successful release build

Build Step

-> ./gradlew clean build uploadArchive

I want environment variables (example: BUILD_USER_ID) to be available during Pre Build Step.

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: Hm...  when you say Pre Build step are you referring to the "Run buildstep before SCM runs"?  Or is this something like "Pre Steps" in a maven build job?  In either case, I am able to see all the Jenkins related environment variables.  Could you elaborate on what you are doing and what kind of setup you have?

Comment: Pre Build is after SCM runs. So, I am trying to release modules. For releasing module, I create staging repo, prepare release, build module, etc. Building module is BUILD step. Creating staging repo and preparing for releasing are pre build steps.

Comment: Why not adding a build step before the gradle build step? If you add a build step, you can move it to the top, so it's the first build step. This build step you can see then as a pre build step.